# How to make iterated data render properly in a table with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Using the following data set how can I make the data render properly in the table?
Each row represents new row for the table and the objects inside each row represents the data for the columns:

```
"result": {
  "data":[
    {
      "row": [
        {name: "Clark Kent", value: "Superman"},
        {name: "Tony Stark", value: "Iron Man"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "row": [
        {name: "Bruce Wayne", value: "Batman"},
        {name: "Peter Parker", value: "Spiderman"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In my component I am doing the following but it doesn't work properly:

```
<Table.Body>
  {_.map(Object.values(result), (path, index) => {
    let returnOptions=[];
    _.map(Object.values(path), (data,i) => {
      data.row.map((item, y) => {
        console.log(item)
        returnOptions.push({
          item: _.get(state, item, '')
        })
      })
    })
    // console.log(returnOptions)
    const testtest = returnOptions.map(option => {return option.item})
    return (
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell >{testtest}</Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    )
  })}
</Table.Body>
```

Desired output that I am looking for:

```
    Table
-----------------
  Col1   | Col2
-----------------
Superman | IronMan
Batman   | Spiderman
```

Comment: are Table.Body, Table.Row and Table.Cell components created by you??

Comment: Hi @Joe'swiZaT thanks for the response. I am using the Table component from the library "semantic-ui-react". It doesn't really matter though. I can also go with regular html table element if it can be figure out how to resolve my issue.

Comment: doesn't matter just curious, i would answer but you already got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<table>
    {data.result.data.map(item => (
        <tr>
            {item.row.map(row => (<td>
                {row.value}
            </td>))}
        </tr>
    ))}
</table>
```

For example I used HTML table

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much Kamil, really appreciate it.